# Correct date format?

Tags: java, date

Just something that is probably very easy, but confusing me greatly, I have a class which calls onto another one.

```
public static int getNumberOfDaysBetweenDates(Date d1, Date d2)
{
    //rest of code
}
```

is being called upon in another part of the file. Only problem is, how exactly do I declare d1 and d2? ive tried a few things, but keep getting hit with incompatible errors etc.

Comment: `DateTime.getNumberOfDaysBetweenDates(1/4/12,1/5/12);`
Just different ways like that, but they all get rejected, because they are not accepted as Date.

Comment: What is you error message? No details? There are at least 2 Date class in Java. java.util.Date and java.sql.Date. Maybe your hint "incompatible errors" means this? If so, you can use full package+class.

Comment: How are you getting a java.util.Date from those strings?

Answer (score 4):

Curia, what you're passing aren't `Date` objects.. they aren't even `String`s. You have to create `Date` objects and then pass to your method and then it will work.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date d = sdf.parse("21/12/2012");
```